# Github action cronjob curl POST doesn't always work

Tags: api, github, curl, cron, github-actions

I've setup a github action on a private repository, free account, as a cron so that runs every day at 9am:

```
name: updates
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 9 * * *'
jobs:
  cron:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Call our API route
        run: |
          curl --request POST \
          --url 'https://mysite.vercel.app/api/myjsfile' \
          --header 'Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
```

but I've noticed that while if I open `https://mysite.vercel.app/api/myjsfile` manually in browser it works as expected, saving all the data in my mongodb (inside `myjsfile.js` it goes through a for loop and save each in a collection), when it gets called via cron either it doesn't work or it goes through 1-2 loops at max.

What am I doing wrong here? I've checked for github action timeouts but it seems the cron timeouts after hours, so it shouldn't be the issue here since the whole process when I open the api url manually it takes about 3-4 minutes

**EDIT 1:** modified to GET request as suggested, but without any changes

**EDIT 2:** thanks to the logging suggested below, which returns:

```
2021-01-27T09:20:35.6297813Z ##[group]Run curl --request GET \
2021-01-27T09:20:35.6298606Z [36;1mcurl --request GET \[0m
2021-01-27T09:20:35.6299479Z [36;1m--url 'https://xxxxxxxxx.vercel.app/api/myjsfile' \[0m
2021-01-27T09:20:35.6301000Z [36;1m--header 'Authorization: ***'[0m
2021-01-27T09:20:35.7007371Z shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
2021-01-27T09:20:35.7008125Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-27T09:20:37.5226619Z   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2021-01-27T09:20:37.5227783Z                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
2021-01-27T09:20:37.5228270Z 
2021-01-27T09:20:37.5229486Z   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
2021-01-27T09:20:38.0606613Z   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
2021-01-27T09:20:39.5213317Z   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
2021-01-27T09:20:40.0623420Z   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
2021-01-27T09:20:41.0637824Z   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0
2021-01-27T09:20:42.0648174Z   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
2021-01-27T09:20:43.0660811Z   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
2021-01-27T09:20:44.0672977Z   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--     0
2021-01-27T09:20:45.0686998Z   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--     0
2021-01-27T09:20:46.0697253Z   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0
2021-01-27T09:20:47.0708765Z   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--     0
2021-01-27T09:20:48.0063092Z   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--     0
2021-01-27T09:20:48.0071894Z 100    68  100    68    0     0      5      0  0:00:13  0:00:12  0:00:01    13
2021-01-27T09:20:48.0073622Z 100    68  100    68    0     0      5      0  0:00:13  0:00:12  0:00:01    17
2021-01-27T09:20:48.0089257Z An error occurred with this application.
2021-01-27T09:20:48.0089948Z 
2021-01-27T09:20:48.0090483Z NO_RESPONSE_FROM_FUNCTION
```

I've seen that there's a `NO_RESPONSE_FROM_FUNCTION` error at the end, and it may have to do with the fact that the plan on vercel is a "hobby" one for now, so it may be the max timeout of 10s for serverless functions as shown in the screenshot below?

[image: vercel general limits]

It's weird though cause when I go to the /api/myjsfile manually as said it works fine, is it because isn't seen as "serverless" by vercell contrary to when it's executed via cronjob?

Comment: When you say "I open https://mysite.vercel.app/api/myjsfile manually in browser", are you literally just browsing to that page? If you are, that'd be making a GET request, whereas your cronjob is making a POST request.

Comment: Yes, in fact my first doubt was about the POST vs GET, how is that it somehow worked anyway with POST? I'll try with GET for the next cron

Comment: No idea how it worked with POST without seeing your JS code; might help if you added that to the question.

Comment: It's a js file in a Next.js environment (so inside the /api/ folder), which within a simple export default function { basically fetches an external API and saves results to mongodb and closes with }. If the GET was it, i'll update you so that you can get the bounty

Comment: It didn't work, I simple wrote GET instead of POST, as anticipated, but didn't work either. Should i get the token somewhere or I leave it as "secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN" ?

Comment: try to enable https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/enabling-debug-logging

Comment: done thank you, i'll update you, besides, is "GITHUB_TOKEN" a placeholder where I was supposed to place my own secret name? or is it an automatic token github uses? now I also have this doubt, cause the doc is not very clear about it

Comment: "GitHub automatically creates a `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret to use in your workflow. You can use the `GITHUB_TOKEN` to authenticate in a workflow run." (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow#about-the-github_token-secret)

Comment: And it means that Github creates a GITHUB_TOKEN which I find somewhere and I should replace the "GITHUB_TOKEN" placeholder with it? or that the "GITHUB_TOKEN" string per se is the secret and I shouldn't touch it?

Comment: It means that `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` will be filled in with the token that is automatically created.

Comment: Updated with the logs, and some more considerations/doubts

Comment: See https://vercel.com/knowledge/how-to-debug-a-502-error for info on how to debug Vercel serverless functions

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't help much, since the logs are realtime only in vercel, I even tried to set a time for the next hr or so in the cron but didn't log anything at the time. I'm also pretty sure it would log a "NO_RESPONSE_FROM_FUNCTION" error as github did. Would be more about finding someone with a similar experience that may point me in the right direction i guess

Comment: this does not answer your question. But when you have stuff which are slow, you may just POST a batch which returns (asynchronously) an id (so user can query the batch status by polling or not). This avoids trouble such as browser timeout, cdn timeout, frontend timeout...
as for how to synchronize the end of processing to the github action, I don't know if you can push from back to github or if you have to poll from github action